# How to move/copy a discussion board item in Sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-discussion-board

How can I create a function that copies some item from one Sharepoint discussion board to another? Everything is quite simple except field name Posted By, MyEditor, and Editor.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a one-time thing, you might look at using the Content Deployment API (there's a [Content Deployment Wizard](http://spdeploymentwizard.codeplex.com/) app that provides a UI for it).

Otherwise, you should be able to set the "posted by" by using something like this (assuming web is an open SPWeb and newItem is a discussion item):

```
SPUser user = web.Users["DOMAIN\\username"];
newItem[SPBuiltInFieldId.Author] = user.ID;
newItem[SPBuiltInFieldId.Editor] = user.ID;
newItem.SystemUpdate();
```